# GetListAdapter returning null in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I have an activity that extends ListActivity. In its onCreate method I perform below:

```
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this, model));
```

I set a custom adapter for my listview widget defined in xml layout.

My custom adapter, InterativeArrayAdapter, extends ArrayAdapter. Model is a class that I have built to manage listview items data.

My problem is in the activity that extends ListActivity: When I handle a button click I perform the following:

```
    public void onClickCompareButton(View view) {
    InteractiveArrayAdapter adapter;
    Set<Integer> checkedItems;
    Iterator<Integer> it;
    Model element;

    adapter = (InteractiveArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
    checkedItems = adapter.getCheckedItems();
    it = checkedItems.iterator();

    int size = checkedItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        element = adapter.getItem(it.next());
        // TODO
    }
}
```

The problem is the cast:

```
adapter = (InteractiveArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
```

adapter gets null value so next line crashes:

```
checkedItems = adapter.getCheckedItems();
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be with the way you set the adapter to your list.

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
 listView.setAdapter(new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this, model));
```

Since you extend ListActivity the ListView should be by default available to your Activity. So you should try this,

```
setListAdapter(new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this, model));
```

**setListAdapter(adapterObj)** - is available when you extend an ListActivity.

Comment: Oh my God! What a mistake! Thanks very much! it works!